# Select multiple features from multiple layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, merge, features, select-by-attribute

I am analysing land use across multiple region.

Each region has its own vector dataset. Each dataset contains the same columns and land use classifications (e.g. 'AC66' or 'TC01'), describing units of land (visually similar to a raster dataset).

Is it therefore possible to select all 'AC66' datapoints from multiple different layers?

The following image displays AC66 for multiple regions. I wish to select all blue data points in one dataset **AND** all pink datapoints in the surrounding datasets:

[image]

Comment: What about using `Merge vector layers` to only have one main layer ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. "Is it posslible?" questions are of limited use, since the answer is pretty much always, "Yes." In this case, the answer appearser to be, "Yes, if you merge the datasets," or "Yes, if you make a view", or "Yes,  if you write a script." If you [Edit] the Question to provide more information about the data, and what you have attempted, a more complete answer might be possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pyqgis. I want to select features where "kkod" field is 428

```
sql = '"kkod"=428' #Adjust this
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values(): #For all layers added to the map
    processing.run("qgis:selectbyexpression", {'INPUT':layer,'EXPRESSION':sql,'METHOD':0}) #Select by query
```

[image]